# How do I get rid of this reflection warning in my clojure source, which has a gen-class?

Tags: clojure

```
 (ns scratch.fastflip
   (:gen-class
    :extends java.util.Random
    :implements clojure.lang.IFn))

 (defn -invoke [^java.util.Random this]
   (.next this 1))
```

Loading the file I get the warning:

```
 ;scratch.coin=> Reflection warning, /home/user/scratch/src/scratch/fastflip.clj:8 - call to next can't be resolved.
 #'scratch.fastflip/-invoke
```

Note I want to get rid of the warning via eliminating the reflection, not via setting warning mechanism to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on 1.3, this is probably because `next` takes an int, not a long, and 1 is an int. But are you sure `next` is what you want to call? If you're doing coin-flipping, I would just use `nextInt(2)`, as `next` looks like implementation internals.

Edit: Here's syntax you can use to do what you want without a reflection warning.

```
(ns test-genclass.core
  (:gen-class
   :extends java.util.Random
   :implements [clojure.lang.IFn]
   :exposes-methods {next inner}))

(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)

(defn -invoke [^test_genclass.core this]
  (.inner this 1))

(defn -main [& args]
  ((test_genclass.core.)))
```

Comment: I'm sure I want to use next. The idea is to implement a faster flipping method since I only care about heads tails.

Comment: Also, casting the clojure long 1 -> int 1 fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work. I don't know what I did to think it fixed it. casting 1 to int doesn't actually cast it to an int.

Comment: @bmillare Added more specific example.

Comment: Copying pasting your code, I'm getting CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test_genclass.core, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:11)

Comment: Hmm I guess I'm not familiar with the protocols for using gen-class. Apparently, you need to only run this code via a compile. You can't just load it.

Comment: The first two sentences in `(doc gen-class)` are "When compiling, generates compiled bytecode[...]and writes the .class file to the `*compile-path*` directory. When not compiling, does nothing."